# Is there a way to prevent Redis AOF log rewrite?

Tags: redis

Is there a configuration option to prevent redis from rewriting the AOF log when it "gets too big"?

Comment: Why would you want to prevent AOF rewrite? It actually helps you to save your disk space, and also after rewrite you get the minimum set of instructions required by redis to roll back to current state.

Comment: If your AOF file gets too big, when it attempts to rewrite itself to disk it will fail due to lack of space, then try again. It results in a rewrite loop that can only be stopped by stopping auto-rewrite.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [redis.conf](https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.6/redis.conf):

```
# Specify a percentage of zero in order to disable the automatic AOF
# rewrite feature.

auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 0
```